# i am trying to include this page but it is show that there is no such file but it exists

Tags: php, include, include-once

```
 if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
     $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
     include "C:\xampp\htdocs\BMO\admin\categories.php";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `echo "C:\xampp\htdocs\BMO\admin\categories.php";` - notice something? https://3v4l.org/EO2Hc Time to go read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @CBroe this is easy to fix; don't have folder names that start with `[nrtvef]` or `[0-7]` or `[xu][0-9a-f]`. ^_^ `/lampp/` would not have this problem.

Comment: Use relative path in includes instead of absolute path.  https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.